# How to create independent adaptive card

Tags: microsoft-teams, power-automate, adaptive-cards

How to create adaptive card with status dropdown and submit button. When user click submit button, based on drop-down value the list item should update.
Is there any way to create card without waiting for response in teams.

Comment: No, it doesn’t work like that.

Comment: As said by @Skin, it is currently not possible.